# Enzyme cannot find child component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

In my test code

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from './../Container'
import Child from './../Child'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'

describe('Component Container', () => {
    it('should renders', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Container/>);
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true) // its work
    });
    it('should renders Child', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Container/>);
        expect(wrapper.find(Child).exists()).toBe(true) // false
    })
})
```

When call renders Child, return false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to import `Child`, you can use:

```
expect(wrapper.find('Child').exists()).toBe(true)
```